# Is there any rest api for sql reporting services in azure?

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I need to create a new sql reporting service using azure powershell cmdlets?? as there is no cmdlet for this i need to use api. so is there any api available for sql reporting in azure??

Answer (score 1):

See this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618886/delete-reports-in-an-sql-azure-sub-folder).

It discusses the use of the [ReportService2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx) web service for managing and executing reports.  This is SOAP rather than REST mind.

However, I don't think the tool allows you to actually create a new instance of Windows Azure SQL Reporting; rather manage an existing instance.  The only approach I know of is [through the portal like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403968.aspx).  They are however [adding new functionality each release to the Windows Azure Powershell](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/07/31/announcing-the-release-of-the-windows-azure-sdk-2-1-for-net.aspx) so it may be a matter of time.

Is this something you need to do on a frequent scheduled basis?

EDIT: Theres a better introduction to [using the ReportService2010 web service here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg552871.aspx#SOAPManagement).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to examine an example

Windows Azure SQL Reporting ReportViewer-SOAP API usage sample
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-SQL-1cfc2d7e